# sort int64 with a number inside

Tags: python

[image: problem]

So I was trying to set up these classes follow the order 1 to 10. However, Class 10 is in between Class 1 and 2. Is there any solution for making this following ascending order?
code I was use is

`data['Product Classification'].value_counts().sort_index()`

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to understand the structure of `data`.

Comment: @apham15 Is ```value_counts``` integer numbers or string with ```Class``` word in the beginning?

Comment: @Nagmat has the right answer.  The string 'Class 10' does properly sort before the string 'Class 2'.  You will have to specify a "key" function to `sort_index`.  That lets you apply a function to each key before it sorts.

Comment: If you want strings representing numbers to sort properly, then you need to ensure that the field width of all the numbers is the same and left-padded with zeros `00, 01, 02 .. 10, 11`

Answer (score 2):

```
data['Product Classification'].value_counts().sort_index(
    key=lambda v : int(v[6:])
)
```